# How to get location (lat,lng) in API 23 and above in Android Programmatically?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-location, android-gps

I am developing an application which enable GPS and get the current location. My code is working fine in all android version expect API 23 i.e. Marshmallows. I am testing in Nexus 5 (API 23), Galaxy Note 3 (API 22).

Here is my code

```
    public void program()
{
     locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES, MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, new MyLocationListener());

    if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(NearBy.this);
        builder.setTitle("Location Service is Not Active");
        builder.setMessage("Please Enable your location services").setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    } else if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses = null;
        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);

            final String cityName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0) + " ";
            String stateName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1) + " ";
            String countryName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2) + " ";
            String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName() + " ";
            String Area = addresses.get(0).getSubAdminArea() + " ";
            String Area1 = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea() + " ";
            String Area2 = addresses.get(0).getLocality() + " ";
            String Area3 = addresses.get(0).getSubLocality();
            Log.e("Locaton", cityName + stateName + countryName + country + Area + Area1 + Area2 + Area3);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting NullpointerException at

```
         addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
```

only in Nexus 5 (API 23). I also granted permission (ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) in both Mainfest and also during run time.

Kindly provide solution for this.

**UPDATED**

I have changed my code. I created a GPSTracker class and I am getting lat, Lng as 0

**GPSTracker.java**

```
  public class GPSTracker extends Activity implements LocationListener {
private final Context mContext;
// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;
Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude

private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);


        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {

        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }

            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return location;
}
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
public void stopUsingGPS() {
    if (locationManager != null) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return;
        }
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }
}


public double getLatitude() {
    if (location != null) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    return latitude;
}

public double getLongitude() {
    if (location != null) {
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    return longitude;
}


public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}


public void showSettingsAlert() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location currentLocation) {

    this.location = currentLocation;
    getLatitude();
    getLongitude();

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {


}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}
}
```

Comment: Can you post logcat output ?

Comment: you should check run time permission  like     if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 &&
                    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( context, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( context, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return  ;
            }

Comment: GPSTracker.java worked for me to get zip code - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Problem**

```
The location obtained may be null if the last know location could not be found due to various reasons. Read about it in the docs [here][2]
```

**Reason/How i debugged it**

1. `getFromLocation` does not throws a nullpointer according to documentation hence the problem is in your location object.

   [Read here about this method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocation(double,%20double,%20int))

**Remedy**

```
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

Check if the location obtained in the above step is NOT NULL and then proceed with the geocoder.

**Code snippet**

```
...
else if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    if(location == null) {
       log.d("TAG", "The location could not be found");
       return; 
    }
    //else, proceed with geocoding.
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
```

**Fetching the location - An example**

[Read here](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html)

**Complete code**

[View it here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location)

Comment: If problem is in my location, then how I will get lat,lng with this same code in other devices which runs in API 22 and below. Actually Now I created a GPSTracker.java and I am getting lat and lng as 0

Comment: @AnishKumar : That is only possible in other devices if the lastKnownLocation was available in them. Try to print the location object in those devices , and you'll see for yourself

Comment: Fine @cafebabe1991. I will let you know shortly.

Comment: `03-22 17:04:13.964 32141-32141/prateektechnosoft.com.demoproject W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference
03-22 17:04:13.965 32141-32141/prateektechnosoft.com.demoproject W/System.err:     at prateektechnosoft.com.demoproject.NearBy.program(NearBy.java:92)
03-22 17:04:13.965 32141-32141/prateektechnosoft.com.demoproject W/System.err:     at prateektechnosoft.com.demoproject.NearBy.onCreate(NearBy.java:54)`

Comment: `03-22 17:04:13.957 32141-32141/prateektechnosoft.com.demoproject D/la: Latitude:0.0, Longitude:0.0
03-22 17:04:13.963 32141-32141/prateektechnosoft.com.demoproject D/Location Object: null`

Comment: I tried to print Location Object in nexus 5, I got Null. But when I run in Other device i got the location.

Comment: yeah. Thanks buddy!!!. Is there any way to sort this ? 

I am pretty surprised, because I just run my old project in nexus 5, which targetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion is 22 and I get the exact location.

Comment: See, the only way to this is to fetch the location only when the conditions for fetching it are met. Check the SettingsApi by google, then follow this tutorial for more help.

https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwid4eaKndTLAhVGc44KHZWIAowQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Ftraining%2Flocation%2Fretrieve-current.html&usg=AFQjCNH26GrSC2AQqRxg9bDqwpGPOViopw&sig2=bUEZvZxIMHdu-gd6gR7Deg&bvm=bv.117218890,d.c2E

 Complete code for fetching the location.... https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107027/discussion-between-cafebabe1991-and-anish-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

First In marshmallow add all permission on run time also. Otherwise Please restart your mobile and then check again.